# Integrating multi scope dagger 2 components

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

### Preconditions

I have the following components:

1. ApplicationCompoennt - With @ApplicationScope - This component contains LogModule. The logmodule @Provides Logger.
2. ActivityComponent with @ActivityScope - This component contains MyActivityModule. Since one can't call the ctor of Activity explicitly, this module is used to inject the activity. This component depends on @ApplicationScope component, to use the Logger.
3. BroadcastComponent with @BroadcastReceiverScope - This component contains BroadcastReceiverModule. Since one can't call the ctor of it explicitly (its present in the Android manifest file), this module is used to inject the broadcast receiver.

### Problem:

I cant create ActivityComponent with 2 dependencies namely ApplicationComponent and BroadcastComponent, they being of different scopes, 
as we cant have dependent components of different scopes

How to get around this problem ?

Comment: `this module is used to inject the broadcast receiver.` sounds good, so why would the activity have to depend on the broadcast component? Just use the module in the activity component. Or please try to explain what you are trying to do instead of what dagger does