# Dagger 2 One controller, dependant on two scoped components

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

So I'm using Dagger 2 for an Android application but let me try to explain my problem without the Android terminology.

Simply, I have one controller that shows the UI. In order to show the appropriate values with their appropriate units, this controller needs to depend on two scoped components, which is impossible.

Here is the case: I have

> - One Controller Component, scoped with @Activity
> - One Application Comonent, scoped with @Singleton
> - One DbComponent - a Database component, scoped with @Application and it is dependant on ApplicationComponent.
> - One PreferencesComponent - again component, scoped with @Application and dependant on ApplicationComponent.

The ControllerComponent needs to depend on both DbComponent, so my controller can get the data that has to be shown, and on PreferencesComponent to show the appropriate units (Celsius, Fahrenheit, m/s, km/h etc).

What would be the best way to implement my graph?

I saw questions, similar to mine, but they didn't help - [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097300/integrating-multi-scope-dagger-2-components), [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830392/dagger-2-injecting-from-multiple-independently-scoped-components-into-a-single)

Comment: Most of those "components" should be modules. That's why it's not working. Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545075/dagger2-and-android/40546157#40546157

Comment: Are you telling me to follow some sort of a "One Component per Scope" pattern or something else? I think the question is partially philosophical. Why (for example) a DbComponent should be only a module while something like networkcomponent should be in a separate comonent instead of just another module?

Comment: The network component is also singleton scoped, is it not? Then it should be a module, part of the singleton component. If you see that answer, `NetworkingComponent` was just a regular `public interface` with the provision methods in it, not an actual component.

Comment: The NetworkComponent is Application scoped. I am looking at this answer right now but I'm not sure I get it correct. Do I understand right that everything which lives as long the app is on and has to be singleton, should be in ControllerComponent and Singleton scoped?

Answer (score 3):

> One Controller Component, scoped with @Activity
>
> One Application Comonent, scoped with @Singleton
>
> One DbComponent - a Database component, scoped with @Application and it is dependant on ApplicationComponent.
>
> One PreferencesComponent - again component, scoped with @Application and dependant on ApplicationComponent.

In reality, [a component should exist per scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545075/dagger2-and-android/40546157#40546157).

So you should have 2 components:

1.) `ApplicationComponent`, marked with `@Singleton`

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules={DbModule.class, PreferencesModule.class, AppModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    // provision methods
}
```

2.) `ControllerComponent`, marked with `@Activity`

```
@Activity
@Component(dependencies={ApplicationComponent.class}, modules={ControllerModule.class})
public interface ControllerComponent extends ApplicationComponent {
    // provision methods
}
```